# Que quiere decir embedded?

Tags: algoritmos

Bien, *embedded* en si mismo se refiere a *incrustar* codigo de un lenguaje en otro, de hecho es exactamente las mismas palabras ...

> [Que es un codigo embedido?](https://es.calameo.com/books/004188656ee6b08e59004)

> En programación o desarrollo de páginas web, embeber significa insertar (incrustar) código de un lenguaje dentro de otro lenguaje.
> En móviles, se habla de contenido embebido en un teléfono cuando un terminal trae por defecto contenidos dentro. Ref : [qué es embeber / embebido (embedded).](https://woko.agency/diccionario/embeber-embebido-embedded/)

> Embeber es un término ligado a la programación que se utiliza para hablar de la acción de incrustar o insertar un contenido elaborado en un lenguaje de programación en otro lenguaje diferente. En el ámbito web, es uno de los mecanismos más empleados cuando se desea enriquecer el contenido de una publicación de cualquier tipo con textos, imágenes o incluso vídeos. Ref: [¿Qué es Embeber y para que sirve? - Neo Wiki | NeoAttack](https://neoattack.com/neowiki/embeber/)

Sin embargo no me termina de quedar claro cuando hacen referencia a la palabra *incrustar* (se refiere a escribir?) o cuando se dice *dentro de un lenguaje*. Mi principal sospecha es que se refiere a escribir codigo de la *implementacion* del lenguaje con otro lenguaje, algo asi como el caso de `Python` donde su principal implementacion (`Cpython`) esta hecha en `C`. Con lo cual la pregunta seria: mi sospecha es cierta? y en caso de no serlo, entonces que es embedded?(sin usar las palabras *incrustar* o *dentro de*)

Comment: Lo primero notar que _"embebido"_ es una mala traducción o _"barbarismo"_ de la palabra original _"embedded"_, cuya traducción correcta sería "incrustado" o "empotrado". La idea del código empotrado es que sigue siendo distinguible del resto del código, sin formar una unidad con él (como daría por pensar al hablar de "embebido").

Answer (score 1):

Cuando se habla de "incrustar" se refiere a escribir, pegar o cualquier forma de meter un fragmento de código dentro de otro. Un código "incrustado" es un fragmento de código que se ejecuta en un contexto o por un intérprete distinto del código que podríamos llamar "padre". En general el código "incrustado " está literalmente dentro del código "padre" y escrito en otro lenguaje. El padre no entiende el código incrustado, lo interpreta como otra cosa, como un string por ejemplo.

```html
<button onclick="alert('estoy incrustado');">
  Click aquí
</button>
```

En el ejemplo, el código "padre" es **html** que tiene un intérprete, `alert('estoy incrustado');` es un fragmento de **JavaScript** que tiene otro intérprete, en este caso ambos intérpretes estan juntos en el navegador.